# How to make word wrap respect indentation in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, word-wrap

Visual Studio has a word wrap feature, but frustratingly it ignores line indents, making the text hard to read. Other text editors (Notepad++, Sublime Text) simulate the indentation of wrapped lines, making code easier to read

How can I make Visual Studio 2012 wrap lines intelligently? Smartly?

See in Notepad++, 'of beer' is wrapped appearing in line with Console

[image: notepad++]

Where as in Visual Studio, 'bottles of beer' juts out into the indentation, making the code shape hard to read.

[image: vs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good news: In Visual Studio 2013, word wrap properly respects indents!

However there's a number of remaining issues with it (eg. around the Home/End keys). Please vote at https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/5574507-fix-behaviour-of-home-end-keys-when-word-wrap-is-e

---

Alas, it's not possible. Bug to the Visual Studio developers at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3285423-wrap-lines-intelligently-simulating-indents- . Please vote for it!

Comment: VS 2017 does not do word wrap indentation as Notepad++ does, it's always off by a few blanks.

Answer (score 1):

This extension does what I want, but only for Visual Studio **2010** :/

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ac95f80f-6cfd-4b67-b0fd-e9c5c8fb27de

NB. I tried hacking the extension manifest to make it install on 2012 but the behaviour went awry. The extension needs a real update

Answer (score 0):

For VS2012, there is an extension 
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a5b5001e-fe7a-4c08-9cf5-96ae5892088a

It does the same thing...

Comment: You linked to the VS2010 version, thus the answer is wrong or pointless. Feel free to update the link.

Comment: This doesn't appear to do anything for me.

Comment: Worked for me... Anyway, VS2013 and hopefully up have this auto-indent built-in (no extensions needed)