# Visual Studio 2013 - How to turn off auto-indentation in code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

There is a post that goes on about Visual Studio with 'intelligent' word wrap in [How to make word wrap respect indentation in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324453/how-to-make-word-wrap-respect-indentation-in-visual-studio)

However - its a personal preference and can make code more unreadable in some cases.

In Visual Studio 2013 - this auto-indentation is default behavior.

How do you in Visual Studio 2013 turn this off?, so we get word-wrapping going back to the previous way - all-left aligned?

There doesn't appear to be an option in Visual Studio Options, or maybe I am missing something.  If it is missing in Visual Studio Options, does anyone know of an add-in that will reset this auto-indentation?

Comment: I still want this in VS 2017. Word wrap back to the first column.

Answer (score -1):

I have VS2010 but try this:

Options/Text Editor/C#/Tabulations and then at identation block select **none**.

PS. You have to **expand** the options, if you select text editor it will show only the general options for text editor.